# JS Hack for Native Regex in Power Query for Excel

Tags: excel, regex, powerbi, powerquery, m

## Background

I wish to perform regex detection (and matching?) in Power Query (M) for Excel, which lacks native support for regex.  Unlike Power BI, Excel lacks the [integrations with R and Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-r-in-query-editor#use-an-r-script-in-power-query-editor), so I cannot use them to outsource the regex operations.

## Approach

Inspired by this [clever hack](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/f5wmtq) from [u/tirlibibi17](https://www.reddit.com/u/tirlibibi17), I have generalized a native solution by integrating M with JavaScript (JS) and its regex functionality.  See the **Solution** section below for my full work.

While I have successfully tested `Rgx_Test()` on a single `text` string, it bogs down at scale, because it regenerates the [`Web.Page()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/web-page) for *every* string being tested.  With the plural **`Rgx_Tests()`**, I aspire to a operate on a *batch of many* such strings, all in one fell swoop.

My "intended script" for `Rgx_Tests()` should improve on the "current script" for `Rgx_Test()`.  The native [`Json.*()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/accessing-data-functions) family in M facilitates the exchange of batch data with the JS script, as represented in JSON notation.  For input, a `list` of `text`s in M becomes an `Array` of `String`s in JS.  For output, an `Array` of `Boolean`s in JS becomes a `list` of `logical`s in M.

## Problem

Unfortunately, a **mysterious failure** has cut short my progress on `Rgx_Tests()`:

- While my current script properly renders a `Boolean` via [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/write), my intended script ***fails* to likewise render a `String` of JSON text**.  This `String` is generated by [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) from the `Array` of `Boolean`s.
- **This problem occurs *only* in M**, and *not* in JS, as demonstrated (below) by the intended script in isolation. Presumably the fault lies with `Web.Page()`, but why should it render a `Boolean` yet fail to render a `String`?
- No error is thrown.  The current script renders the `Boolean` in a text block, where I can easily find it.  With the intended script, **this text block is simply *missing***.

See  the **Debugging** section below for details.

## Question

**What is the origin of this mysterious failure, and how do I fix it?**

I *do* know that a JS script, with errors in syntax or at runtime, will yield this behavior.  However, that JS script (below) runs perfectly on its own.  **Perhaps functions like `JSON.stringify()` are incompatible with the version of JS that M is using?**

---

## Debugging

### Current Script for `Rgx_Test()`

My current script works smoothly, and renders raw text for M to interpret as a `logical`.

I take the single `text` string in M, and convert it via my helper `Json_Stringify()`...

```m
Json_Stringify("A1")
```

...into its JSON representation...

```html
"A1"
```

...which I "inject" (splice) into the JS script below.

```html
<html><body><script>
    //        ˇˇˇˇ
    var txt = "A1";
    //        ^^^^
    var ptn = "[a-z]\\d";
    var flg = "i";
    var rgx = new RegExp(ptn, flg);
    var tst = rgx.test(txt);
    document.write(tst);
</script></body></html>
```

It renders the result as raw text...

```html
true
```

...which I drill and extract via `Web.Page()`:

[image: 7]

I then parse it via [`Logical.FromText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/logical-fromtext)...

```m
Logical.FromText("true")
```

...to yield a `logical` result.

```m
true
```

### Intended Script for `Rgx_Tests()`

I aspire to the script below, which succeeds in JS but *fails* to render JSON text for M to interpret as a `list` of `logical`s.

I take a `list` of `text`s in M, and convert it via my helper `Json_Stringify()`...

```m
Json_Stringify({"A1", "2b", "c_3", "d4_"})
```

...into its JSON representation...

```html
["A1","2b","c_3","d4_"]
```

...which I "inject" (splice) into the JS script below:

```html
<html><body><script>
    //         ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ
    var txts = ["A1","2b","c_3","d4_"];
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    var ptn = "[a-z]\\d";
    var flg = "i";
    var rgx = new RegExp(ptn, flg);
    function rgx_test(txt) {return rgx.test(txt)};
    var tsts = txts.map(rgx_test);
    var out = JSON.stringify(tsts);
    document.write(out);
</script></body></html>
```

It *should* render the results as (JSON) text...

```html
[true,false,false,true]
```

...which I could drill and extract via `Web.Page()`:

[image: 9]

I could then parse via [`Json.Document()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/json-document)...

```m
Json.Document("[true,false,false,true]")
```

...to yield a `list` of `logical` results.

```m
{true, false, false, true}
```

#### Failure

Unfortunately, the corresponding `record` for this text block is *entirely absent* from the `table` output by `Web.Page()`:

[image: 11]

### Intended `Rgx_Tests()`

This should test a `list` of `text` strings against a regex `pattern`, and return a `list` of the `logical` results.

```m
let Rgx_Tests = (
    texts as list,
    pattern as text,
    optional insensitive as nullable logical
) as nullable list =>
    let
        txts = Json_Stringify(texts),
        ptn = Json_Stringify(pattern),
        flg = Json_Stringify(Rgx_Flags(false, false, insensitive)),
        
        html = "<html><body><script>
            var txts = " & txts & ";
            var ptn = " & ptn & ";
            var flg = " & flg & ";
            var rgx = new RegExp(ptn, flg);
            function rgx_test(txt) {return rgx.test(txt)};
            var tsts = txts.map(rgx_test);
            var out = JSON.stringify(tsts);
            document.write(out);
        </script></body></html>",
        
        page = Web.Page(html),
        out = page{0}[
            Data
        ]{[
            Name = "HTML"
        ]}[Children]{[
            Name = "BODY"
        ]}[Children]{[
            Kind = "Text"
        ]}[
            Text
        ],
        
        result = try Json.Document(out) otherwise null
    in
        result
in
    Rgx_Tests
```

---

## Solution

Here are my functions that currently *do* work.

### `Rgx_Flags()`

This helper generates the string of [regex flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) for JS.

```m
let Rgx_Flags = (
    optional hasIndices as nullable logical,
    optional global as nullable logical,
    optional ignoreCase as nullable logical,
    optional multiline as nullable logical,
    optional dotAll as nullable logical,
    optional unicode as nullable logical,
    optional unicodeSets as nullable logical,
    optional sticky as nullable logical
) as text =>
    let
        MOD_SEP = "",
        MOD_NOT = "",
        MOD_FLAGS = [
            hasIndices  = "d",
            global      = "g",
            ignoreCase  = "i",
            multiline   = "m",
            dotAll      = "s",
            unicode     = "u",
            unicodeSets = "v",
            sticky      = "y"
        ],
        
        ind = if hasIndices  = true then MOD_FLAGS[hasIndices]  else MOD_NOT,
        glo = if global      = true then MOD_FLAGS[global]      else MOD_NOT,
        ign = if ignoreCase  = true then MOD_FLAGS[ignoreCase]  else MOD_NOT,
        mul = if multiline   = true then MOD_FLAGS[multiline]   else MOD_NOT,
        dot = if dotAll      = true then MOD_FLAGS[dotAll]      else MOD_NOT,
        uni = if unicode     = true then MOD_FLAGS[unicode]     else MOD_NOT,
        uns = if unicodeSets = true then MOD_FLAGS[unicodeSets] else MOD_NOT,
        sti = if sticky      = true then MOD_FLAGS[sticky]      else MOD_NOT,
        
        result = Text.Combine({ind, glo, ign, mul, dot, uni, uns, sti}, MOD_SEP)
    in
        result
in
    Rgx_Flags
```

### `Json_Stringify()`

This helper converts a `value` into its JSON representation.

```m
let Json_Stringify = (
    value as any,
    optional encoding as nullable number
) as nullable text =>
    Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue(value, encoding), encoding)
in
    Json_Stringify
```

### `Rgx_Test()`

This tests a single `text` string against a regex `pattern`, and returns the `logical` result.

```m
let Rgx_Test = (
    text as text,
    pattern as text,
    optional insensitive as nullable logical
) as nullable logical =>
    let
        txt = Json_Stringify(text),
        ptn = Json_Stringify(pattern),
        flg = Json_Stringify(Rgx_Flags(false, false, insensitive)),
        
        html = "<html><body><script>
            var txt = " & txt & ";
            var ptn = " & ptn & ";
            var flg = " & flg & ";
            var rgx = new RegExp(ptn, flg);
            var tst = rgx.test(txt);
            document.write(tst);
        </script></body></html>",
        
        page = Web.Page(html),
        tst = page{0}[
            Data
        ]{[
            Name = "HTML"
        ]}[Children]{[
            Name = "BODY"
        ]}[Children]{[
            Kind = "Text"
        ]}[
            Text
        ],
        
        result = try Logical.From(tst) otherwise null
    in
        result
in
    Rgx_Test
```

Comment: Was there a question you had, or was this to memorialize your achievement?

Comment: @horseyride My question is implied under the **Problem** section: **what is this mysterious failure, and how do I fix it?**  Any "achievements" would naturally belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Gotcha.  I guess I got lost along the way. Hope someone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77769467) from [@DavideBacci](https://stackoverflow.com/u/18345037), I have found a fairly stable solution.

- As requested in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77767792), it improves performance by using [`Web.Page()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/web-page) only once, rather than for every string in `texts`.
- As cautioned by Davide, it avoids *"high order array functions like map...[and] loops"*, which are likely forbidden by *"the web container in PQ"*.  It also avoids [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), as I myself diagnosed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77767792/77769467#comment137106890_77769467).
- Furthermore, it requires *no* literal separators (like `'|'`), which must otherwise be parsed.

## Solution

### `Rgx_Tests_2()`

Using the original helpers `Json_Stringify()` and `Rgx_Flags()`, this improvement on `Rgx_Tests()` actually *works* in Power Query.

```m
let Rgx_Tests_2 = (
    texts as list,
    pattern as text,
    optional insensitive as nullable logical
) as nullable list =>
    let
        // Constants.
        JS_NEW = "#(lf)",
        HTML_TAG = "<br>",
        
        // Workflow.
        result = if List.IsEmpty(texts) then
            {}
        else
            let
                strs = List.Transform(texts, Json_Stringify),
                ptn = Json_Stringify(pattern),
                flg = Json_Stringify(Rgx_Flags(null, null, insensitive)),
                tag = Json_Stringify(HTML_TAG),
                
                lines = List.Transform(strs, each
                    "document.write(tag + rgx.test(" & _ & "));"
                ),
                code = Text.Combine(lines, JS_NEW),
                
                html = "<html><body><script>
                    var ptn = " & ptn & ";
                    var flg = " & flg & ";
                    var tag = " & tag & ";
                    var rgx = new RegExp(ptn, flg);
                    " & code & "
                </script></body></html>",
                
                page = Web.Page(html),
                out = page{0}[Data]{[
                    Name = "HTML"
                ]}[Children]{[
                    Name = "BODY"
                ]}[Children],
                exprs = Table.SelectRows(out, each [Kind] = "Text")[Text],
                
                lgls = try List.Transform(exprs, Logical.FromText) otherwise null
            in
                lgls
    in
        result
in
    Rgx_Tests_2
```

### Script for `Rgx_Tests_2()`

I take a `list` of `text`s in M, and represent them as JS literals via my helper `Json_Stringify()`:

```m
List.Transform({"A1", "2b", "c_3", "d4_"}, Json_Stringify)
```

Then I [`.Transform()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/list-transform) these into lines of code, which [`.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/write) their [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) results to the page, and I [`.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/text-combine) them into a single block...

```html
document.write(tag + rgx.test("A1"));
document.write(tag + rgx.test("2b"));
document.write(tag + rgx.test("c_3"));
document.write(tag + rgx.test("d4_"));
```

...which I "inject" (splice) into the JS script below:

```html
<html><body><script>
    var ptn = "[a-z]\\d";
    var flg = "i";
    var tag = "<br>";
    var rgx = new RegExp(ptn, flg);
    
 // ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ
    document.write(tag + rgx.test("A1"));
    document.write(tag + rgx.test("2b"));
    document.write(tag + rgx.test("c_3"));
    document.write(tag + rgx.test("d4_"));
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
</script></body></html>
```

It renders the results in *separate blocks* of plain text...

> true

> false

> false

> true

...which I drill and extract via `Web.Page()`.

[image: 11]

Finally I parse via [`Logical.FromText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/logical-fromtext)...

```m
List.Transform({"true", "false", "false", "true"}, Logical.FromText)
```

...to yield a `list` of `logical` results.

```m
{true, false, false, true}
```

Comment: Good work Greg 

Comment: Thanks @DavideBacci!  When it comes to etiquette, which of our two answers should I mark as "accepted"?  While my answer is technically the most compact and stable, your answer identified the problem and prototyped the linear solution.  But we should also consider which answer will be most helpful to future viewers...

Comment: Hi Greg - I'm not 100% sure but it makes sense to mark yours as the answer to me.

Comment: An upvote for my answer would be appreciated though ;)

Comment: @DavideBacci  _"An upvote for my answer would be appreciated"_.  Sure thing!  I actually upvoted it already, back during our discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77767792/77769467#comment137106842_77769467).

Comment: @DavideBacci  As promised in my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77767792/77769467#comment137106964_77769467), I have prototyped an M equivalent of [**`tidyselect`**](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org) in R.  Check it out [**here**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288977) on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)!

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the web container in PQ is protected and does not allow high order array functions like map nor does it allow loops. The way to solve this is to use PQ to generate a series of linear statements for JS to execute. The following should get you where you need:

[image]

```
let 
    texts ={"A1", "A2", "A3"},
    pattern = "[a-z]\\d",
    insensitive = true, 

    ptn = Json_Stringify(pattern),
    flg = Json_Stringify(Rgx_Flags(false, false, insensitive)),

    items = List.Count(texts),

    a = List.Generate(
        () => [x = 0,  y = ""],  
        each [x] <= items,       
        each [x = [x] + 1,    
        y = "var txt"& Text.From(x) &" = '" & texts{x-1} & "';" ],   
        each  [y]                               
    ),

    b = List.Generate(
        () => [x = 0,  y = ""],  
        each [x] <= items,       
        each [x = [x] + 1,    
        y = "out = out + rgx.test(txt"& Text.From(x) &") + '|' ;" ],   
        each  [y]                               
    ),
    html = "<html><body><script>
           
            var ptn = " & ptn & ";
            var flg = " & flg & ";
            var rgx = new RegExp(ptn, flg);" &
            
            Text.Combine(a, "#(lf)") & 

            "var out = '';" & 

            Text.Combine(b, "#(lf)") & 

            "document.write(out);
        </script></body></html>",
        
        page = Web.Page(html),
    Data = page{0}[Data],
    Children = Data{0}[Children],
    Children1 = Children{1}[Children]
in
    Children1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, @DavideBacci!  However, I am unconvinced that this is the root problem: _"the web container...does not allow high order array functions like map nor does it allow loops. "_.  You see, the same failure occurred _even without_ the `*.map()` code; it was the addition of _`JSON.stringify()`_ that made the difference.  I will update my question to clarify this.  **Does the web container forbid even `JSON.stringify()` as being too "high order"?**

Comment: Stringify is a red herring. Try and run a simple array.map function or for loop and it fails. The problem is that any JS errors are swallowed so you can't see them and get a blank result.

Comment: The solution provided will side step your performance issues of creating a new web container each time.

Comment: You need some way to loop the regex in JS and the container is protected so the only way I could think of to iterate your list was to precompute the statements to be executed in the JS environment. It isn't unusual to protect a container to stop run away processes.

Comment: _"Stringify is a red herring."_  I think it's actually _both_ `JSON.stringify()` and _also_ `*.map()`.  The script fails with `stringify()` and without `map()`, yet it also fails with `map()` and without `stringify()`.  This is disappointing, because it forces me to treat `Logical.FromText()` as the _inverse_ of string coercion in `document.write()`.  This assumption is obviously less stable than treating `Json.Document()` as the inverse of `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Possibly - I was more focused on how to solve the issue. Have you tried to the solution I provided to see if it scales?

Comment: _"Have you tried to the solution I provided to see if it scales?"_  Not yet—I've mostly been concerned with getting it to work _at all_.  I do worry that, when operating on very many `texts`, the approach (two JS lines for every `text`) might cause either **(1)** the whole `html` string to exceed some size limit in M, or **(2)** the `<script>` itself to exceed some size limit in JS or HTML.  Can you speak to either of those possibilities?

Comment: _"The solution provided will side step your performance issues of creating a new web container each time."_  Many thanks for your effort on this!  I look forward to testing it out.  :)  FYI, I am working concurrently on an M equivalent of [**`tidyselect`**](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/articles/syntax.html) in R, generalized to any data structure with named fields.

Comment: I can't say as it is not documented at all. The only way to know is to test and see what happens. I think you're exploring the very boundaries of what PQ can offer. Let us know how you get on. It may be possible to have a single List.Generate() and a single line of JS per item in your list. I used two for clarity.

Comment: I managed to refine this linear idea into the elegant [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77791459), which is likely optimal under our current constraints.