# Expression similar to Regex_Replace in Tableau in PowerQuery editor of Power BI

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerquery, tableau-desktop

I want to implement something similar to regex_replace of Tableau in PowerBI

From the internet, I got this video: [Using Regular Expressions in Power Query](https://youtu.be/ggrGg6zsaHc?feature=shared)

I modified my script to use str.replace method in JS:

```
(regex as text, str as text, replacement as text) =>

let

    html = "<script>var regex = " & regex & "; var str = """ & str & """; var res = str.replace(regex, '" & replacement & "'); document.write(res)</script>",

    replacedText = Web.Page(html)[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}

in

    replacedText`
```

Now I want to implement something similar to loops of regex_replace in Tableau.
I want to pass a list of regex, a string , and then a list of replacement text corresponding to the regex.
I tried but the query gave error upon running.

I tried following:

```
(regex as list, str as text, replacements as list) =>

let

    regexList = List.Transform(regex, each Text.From(_)),

    replacementsList = List.Transform(replacements, each Text.From(_)),



    // Ensure both lists have the same number of elements

    minLength = List.Min({List.Count(regexList), List.Count(replacementsList)}),

    regexString = "[" & Text.Combine(List.FirstN(regexList, minLength), ",") & "]",

    replacementsString = "[" & Text.Combine(List.FirstN(replacementsList, minLength), ",") & "]",



    html = "<script>

    let modifiedString = '" & str & "';

    let regex = " & regexString & ";

    let replacements = " & replacementsString & ";

    if (regex.length === replacements.length) {

        regex.forEach((reg, index) => {

            modifiedString = modifiedString.replace(new RegExp(reg, 'g'), (match, ...capturedGroups) => {

                const replacement = replacements[index];

                const replacedString = replacement.replace(/\\$(\\d+)/g, (match, groupIndex) => {

                    const capturedGroupIndex = parseInt(groupIndex, 10) - 1;

                    return capturedGroups[capturedGroupIndex] || '';

                });

                return replacedString;

            });

        });

        document.write(modifiedString);

    } else {

        document.write('Error: Number of regex patterns does not match the number of replacement strings.');

    }

    </script>"

in

    html`
```

This gave following error:

```
Expression.Error: There weren't enough elements in the enumeration to complete the operation.

Details:

    [List]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS Hack for Native Regex in Power Query for Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77767792/js-hack-for-native-regex-in-power-query-for-excel)